# Scalar valued function from SQL Server not returning value when called from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I was given this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_WEBGIS_ISSUE_NUM]
    ()
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @v_new_num int, @v_new_issue_num varchar(50);
    
    SET @v_new_num = (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
                      FROM [dbo].[WEBGIS_ISSUE] 
                      WHERE [ISSUE_NUM] LIKE  CONCAT(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMM'), '%'));

    IF @v_new_num < 10 
        SET @v_new_issue_num = CONCAT(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMM'), '00', @v_new_num);

    ELSE IF @v_new_num < 100
        SET @v_new_issue_num = CONCAT(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMM'), '00', @v_new_num);

    ELSE
        SET @v_new_issue_num = CONCAT(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMM'), @v_new_num);
    
    RETURN @v_new_issue_num 
END;
```

I tried calling it from the following C# code

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = cnn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "[NEPS].[dbo].[GET_WEBGIS_ISSUE_NUM]";

//add any parameters the stored procedure might require
if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) //cmd.Connection.Open();
{
    cnn.Open();
    var o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    //blabla
    cnn.Close();
}
```

but when I debug the code, I kept on receiving null.

Notes: the connection is ok, it is connected, when I tried changing the function's name it yields an error and when I checked through the SQL Server it also returns an appropriate return value.

Comment: `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`? `GET_WEBGIS_ISSUE_NUM` isn't a Stored Procedure; it's a scalar function...

Comment: You need to use `CommandType.Text` and run `SELECT * FROM dbo.GET_WEBGIS_ISSUE_NUM()` - but this really **BADLY** smells like a hack doing somewhat the same thing as an `IDENTITY` column - just not properly and safely........

Comment: Perhaps a `SEQUENCE` would be a better choice if it is trying to serve a purpose similar to an `IDENTITY` but for multiple tables. `SEQUENCE` is available on all supported (included those in extended support) versions of SQL Server, so if that is what you are after I see no reason why you wouldn't use it.

Comment: You need an actual query `SELECT dbo.GET_WEBGIS_ISSUE_NUM()`. Although why this function even exists is another question. At the very least it should be an *inline* Table Valued Function, which is much faster. You also need to dispose your connection and command objects with `using`. And you don't need `if (cmd.Connection.State` there is no reason for it to be open if you just created it

Comment: Be aware that this approach is inherently broken if there is more than one client at a time getting numbers this way, as it doesn't (and can't) ensure numbers aren't issued multiple times. This is why identities and sequences exist. And while it is possible to rewrite the logic to be safe under concurrency, this cannot be done in the function alone (needing, at the very least, client-initiated transactions, but more obviously a stored procedure that combines the number generation with an insert).

Comment: Last but not least, trying to generate a "unique" number using `COUNT(*) + 1` is highly suspect, as it seems this would easily break if records are ever removed (even without concurrency), so you'd have to commit to a table that is absolutely append-only. An approach based on `MAX` seems more stable (but still not safe under concurrency on its own, mind you).

Comment: @JeroenMostert i somehow think of a similar approach but the whole db is a dummy db given to me by my colleague. and it comes from an old system. I'll probably change it later but great advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating a scalar function as a stored procedure, which is the wrong type for this type of execution. You need to 'CommandType.Text' with scalar functions.

Other notes on the `C#` part :

- use `using` blocks with `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` (let the using clause handles the dispose and close connection parts for you).
- the query should be declared as `const string`
- always end the query with a semicolon (even if it's running in the SQL Server without it).
- avoid using short names, choose a readable naming for your variables.

Here is the C# code :

```
const string query = "SELECT [NEPS].[dbo].[GET_WEBGIS_ISSUE_NUM]();";

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();

        // do stuff
    }
```

For the function `GET_WEBGIS_ISSUE_NUM` perhaps you can avoid the extra `IF`s with this line :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_WEBGIS_ISSUE_NUM]
    ()
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @v_new_num int, @v_new_issue_num varchar(50);
    
    SET @v_new_num = (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
                      FROM [dbo].[WEBGIS_ISSUE] 
                      WHERE [ISSUE_NUM] LIKE  CONCAT(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMM'), '%'));

    SET @v_new_issue_num, FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMM') + RIGHT('000' + CAST(@v_new_num AS VARCHAR), 4);
    
    RETURN @v_new_issue_num 
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more common to use a `SELECT` statement to return a scalar function result. When you use `EXECUTE` (due to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`), you need to also specify a return parameter and retrieve the result from the parameter after execution:

```
var result = cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
result.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //ExecuteScalar will work too but the result is null and you still need to use the parameter
var o = result.Value;
```

As noted in the comments to your question, consider the concurrency implications of this approach. Duplicate values will be returned until the row count changes.